# YouTube API retrieve URL of unlisted or private livestream?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use the YouTube API to check for a current livestream and get it's URL. The livestream is UNLISTED.

I can successfully get information on my PUBLIC livestream from my channel using this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=MyChannelId&type=video&eventType=live&key=MyApiKey
```

However it does not return any results when the livestream is UNLISTED.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I am using PHP if that matters.

It appears that this is probably what I am trying to implement: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

And perhaps I will need to use liveStream or liveBroadcast? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started

Comment: So it appears that using an API Key is for PUBLIC accessible information only and does not grant you access to any UNLISTED or PRIVATE information. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started "These API calls do not access any private user data."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended feature for any UNLISTED videos/streams. They cannot be accessed like regular vids. UNLISTED vids can only be accessed through:

> anyone who knows the video's unique video ID can retrieve the video
>   metadata.

as mentioned in [Youtube properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos).

Also Jeff Posnick of Youtube answered in [this google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/P2z8gc0W51o):

> The public videos feed doesn't contain any information about private
>   or unlisted videos, so they won't be returned in the results.

Comment: But what about accessing your own unlisted videos/streams via your own API keys?